# Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $X$ and define $d(A, B) = \inf\{d(a, B) | a ∈ A\}.$ Then $ \ d(A, B) = \ d(B, A)$ .True/false

Tags: general-topology

Is  the following statement True or False ?

Given  (X,d)  is  a metric space  and let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $X$ and define:
$d(A, B) = \inf\{d(a, B) | a ∈ A\}$ .
Then $ \ d(A, B) =  \ d(B, A)$.

## My attempt;

This statement is false.  If I take $X= \mathbb{R}$, $A =(0,1)$ and $B= [2,3]$, then a contradiction pops up.

Is  my logic correct or not?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, It is true....Can you explain why do you see any contradiction,here, please?

Comment: @dmtri, d(A,B) =  1/2  if  i take  a = 1/2  and   d(B,A)  = 0  if b= 1/2

Comment: $d(A,B)=1$, not $1/2$...

Comment: @dmtri  im not getting  how d(A,B) =1  ???   here  im asking infimum     as 1/2  is less then  1

Comment: If it we're $1/2$ you should find 2 elements that  are at most $3/4$ far away... Can you?

Comment: @stupid What do you mean by taking $b = 1/2$? It does not lie in $B$.

Comment: @xbh $1/2 \in (0,1) $

Comment: Maybe you would see if I write $$d(A, B) = \inf_{a\in A} (d(a,B))?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is true.

HINT:

Prove that $$\inf\{d(a,B):a \in A\}=\inf\{d(a,b):a \in A,b \in B \}=\inf\{d(b,A):b \in B\}$$

It is not difficult.